# Query is taking lot of time... how to fix it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my SQL Server database that has 6 columns as below

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    VersionID int NOT NULL,
    EventNum int NOT NULL,
    LossLevelID int NOT NULL,
    PerspCode char(2) NOT NULL,
    Loss float NOT NULL
)
```

Here first 4 columns are the composite primary key.

I don't have any indexes yet.

The below query is taking forever. How to improve the performance?

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    T1.EventNum, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN T1.PERSPCODE = 'GR' THEN LOSS END) Gross  
FROM 
    ART.[LA].[Table1] T1 WITH (NOLOCK)  
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT EventNum
            FROM Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet
            WHERE RegionPerilId = 27)  
    AND EventNum IN (110000002, 110000003, 110000016, 110000019, 110000034, 110000066, 110000086, 110000116, 110000118, 110000136)
GROUP BY 
    T1.EventNum 
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN T1.PERSPCODE = 'GR' THEN LOSS END) > + CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
ORDER BY 
    EventNum DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried the query in SQL Server Performance Monitor? You should also look at the query plan in Management Studio and add indexes or change the query to eliminate table scans.

Comment: please show a query plan. But the obvious thing is to create indexes on AIREventSet regionPerilID and Table1 eventnum

Comment: 1. That `exists` clause is not doing anything, remove it or join it to T1 in the where clause. 2. Why NOLOCK, if you are not sure then do not use it. 3. To profile a query you need to start by looking at the generated Query Plan, do this from within SSMS.

Comment: `I don't have any indexes yet`. Well add a index.  Also your `EXIST` doesnt make sense. Is a constant value.

Comment: Well what does the actual execution plan tell you??

Comment: I see only 5 columns in your table?, and 4 of them are the primary key?

Comment: `SUM(...) > CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(10))`?, what could possibly be the point of that?

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.    The `EXISTS` expression makes no sense.  Normally, this would be correlated.  So, I'm guessing that you intend:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet aes
        WHERE aes.RegionPerilId = 27 and aes.EventNum = t1.EventNum
       )
```

Second, the `HAVING` is awkward to say the least.  Why would you compare a numeric `SUM()` to a character?  Instead:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN T1.PERSPCODE = 'GR' THEN LOSS END) > 0
```

The `+` is a non-op.  The expression would be converted back to a number anyway because of the comparison.

Then the first index I would go for (assuming the above `EXISTS` is correct) is:  `AIREventSet(EventNum, RegionPerilId)`.